# How to implement Multithreading in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to implement multithreading in my wpf application.I have a list of tables and I need generate data files for each table concurrently.

Suppose I have a function called GenerateFiles,

```
  public void GenerateFiles()
    {
        //creating scripts
    }
```

and I have

```
  foreach(var table in tables)
      { 
     GenerateFiles();
      }
```

How can genrate the files using GenerateFiles() concurrently using threads?
Is it correct ?

```
while(tables.count)
 {
      Thread th = new Thread();
      oThread.Start(new ThreadStart(GenerateFiles));
 }
```

How can I implement this using Multithreading ?

Comment: You may wan to rethink this. Parallelizing I/O is not always a good idea. On a SSD it might be a little faster, on a HDD it will be (a lot) slower.

Answer (score 2):

With your code you move the generation of the Files to a background thread. If you want to create them parallel you can use:

```
Parallel.ForEach(tables, table => 
{ 
  GenerateFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the files to be generated in the background and not affect the UI, you may want to wrap this inside a Task.

```
    Task.Run(()=>
    {
       Parallel.ForEach(tables, table => 
       { 
           GenerateFiles();
       }
    });
```